# When to apt-get upgrade

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, gnome-terminal

It seems that every time I install software an `apt-get update` is helpful but when exactly is an `apt-get upgrade` necessary? Or perhaps, when is it helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note that for `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` you must first run an `update` to get the list of packages to determine what actually needs updated.**

---

This is a breakdown of the `apt-get` commands:

- `update` - **Only** updates the software list.
- `upgrade` - **Only** upgrades to newer versions of the same files.
- `dist-upgrade` - upgrades to newer software versions (same as `upgrade`) **and** installs new software.

So to make get a completely upgraded system allyou have to do is:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The most common new files are new kernel versions, since new ones are installed instead of the old one just getting replaced, so that you can run an older one if it breaks the install in some way.

Comment: So, if I am not currently aware of any software upgrades then simply run `apt-get dist-upgrade` whenever an update is needed?

Comment: @BrassApparatus No you need to run apt.get update first or there will be nothing new to install.

Comment: @Alvar: need to mention that `upgrade` will not install/remove any new file.

Comment: @Alvar: yeah, neat :)

Comment: @Alvar no problem, just wanted to improve the formatting.